# HTTP Post Request: 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: post, cors, httprequest

I have the following problem:

My server responds to an HTTP POST with a 401 error. In the same webapp, I'm able to use an HTTP GET request and that works fine. I tested the POST request with postman and I'm able to get data successfully (so at least it's working)...

Request code (copied from Postman):

```
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        "query": {
          "objectTypeId": "168"
        }
      });

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.withCredentials = true;

      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
        }
      });

      xhr.open("POST", <here is my url>);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("crossdomain", "true");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXX");

      xhr.send(data);
```

Most of the threads I found related to this problem are pointing at the CORS configuration, but I think this is working because the get-request works. Anyways, here's the CORS configuration:

web.xml:

```
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.configurationFile</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/cors.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

cors.properties:

```
cors.allowGenericHttpRequests = true
cors.allowOrigin=*
cors.supportsCredentials = true
cors.supportedMethods=GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
cors.supportedHeaders=*
```

Comment: What's the actual body of the 401 unauthorized response?

Comment: Failed to load url1: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mywebapp' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Okay, well that's _definitely_ a CORS issue.

Comment: but y is the http get request working?...

Comment: GET requests are assumed to not modify state and therefore to not be a security risk.

Comment: hmmm u have any tips?

Comment: What happens if you disable `xhr.setRequestHeader("crossdomain", "true");`?

Comment: weird oO i get the same error.
But the auth 100% right...

Comment: Is this against a dev server or production?

Comment: why? its a dev server

Comment: Because if it was against production it would definitely be a cross-origin request - if it's just against a dev server then your request wouldn't be a cross-origin request.

Comment: it is a cross-origin-request. The api is running on port 8060 and my node.js server on 3000

Comment: Then refer to my answer, below. You need to have an OPTIONS response.

Answer (score 0):

This is, in fact, a CORS issue. Your API needs to answer those OPTIONS requests properly otherwise the browser is going to block the request. Relevant external link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Other people on SO have also provided other, more in-depth answers to this problem. A great long-form answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/1003650).

Comment: i take a look at it. Thanks a lot for now :)

Comment: Meh... i tryed this curl request and my answer doesnt help me... the guy in this thread doesnt talk about a 401 response :/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9F19A2240C0379723974376E8FB6FD19; Path=/; HttpOnly
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="x-gateway"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 12:17:56 GMT

Comment: hmmmm.... so it seems that u have to pass ur login credentials in curl in the url itself... like: http://username:password@theApiURL.... now i get my 204 response in curl:
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7C96B00F0E58FBC901CA57F30182F5C9; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Application-Context: os-gateway:prod:80
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myurl
Vary: Origin
Allow: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 08:48:46 GMT

but somehow when i run my app in the browser it still says: 401 Unauthorized

any ideas?

Comment: As I have said before, this is a CORS issue. CORS issues crop up in the browser but not via browserless HTTP clients like Postman, curl etc. The fact that you receive 401 and the other guy got 403 is irrelevant - the fundamental issue is the same and the difference is a result of your having different servers with different CORS middleware.